# How to round of CGFloat value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rounding, cgcontext, cgfloat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSNumberFormatter for rounding up float values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427210/nsnumberformatter-for-rounding-up-float-values)

Currently, I calculate the scaling factor by using :

```
CGFloat scale = CGContextGetCTM(context).a;
NSLog(@"SCALE : %f", scale);
```

I receive a floating point value as : 0.124979, 0.249958, 0.499917. How can I use roundf to get it convert to 0.125, 0.250, 0.500 respectively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this........

```
NSLog(@"SCALE : %.3f", scale);
NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", theFloat];
```

Stolen from [Previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427210/nsnumberformatter-for-rounding-up-float-values)

Comment: Thanks. But how can I convert the rounding in this : CGFloat scale = CGContextGetCTM(context).a;

Comment: try NSLog(@"SCALE: %.3fg",scale);

Comment: I dont have mac now.. so I cant able to give the answer exactly :(

Comment: when I do NSLog(@"SCALE : %.3f", scale); it gives me correct output. But I want to use scale for future and not only to display it.

Comment: @lifemoveson: If you dont get the desired output means dont mark this as accepted answer. Then only you can able to get the correct answer from the other users.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I thought accepted answer mean if its the correct answer. I have changed the code again.

Comment: correct means it answered the question you were asking, did it?

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you want a rounded number that is still a float but only out to 3 decimals and not just for display purposes?  Is that what you are asking?   IEEE floating point numbers are a real pain.  You can assign foo = 1.5 and then you'll end up with 1.499999999 and if you then go say `if ( foo == 1.5 )` it'll fail.  Just seems like a bug to me, but there's long descriptions about why this is "correct" on the net.  Seems like ivory-tower-correct and real-world-useless to me.

So, some possibilities.  I wonder if multiplying by 1000 and then rounding up to the integer value and then dividing by 1000 will work... Course the same IEEE floating-bug, sorry *spec* might still bite you... worth a try.

Got myself curious and wrote a quick test:

```
CGFloat foo = 0.124979;
NSLog(@"foo is: %f", foo );
NSInteger ifoo = ceil(foo * 1000.0);
foo = ifoo / 1000.0;
NSLog( @"ifoo is: %d, and back to foo is: %f", ifoo, foo );
```

outputs this (in the simulator anyway):

```
test[5127:207] foo is: 0.124979
test[5127:207] ifoo is: 125, and back to foo is: 0.125000
```

so that might do what you want.

luck.

Answer (score 0):

Look this stackoverflow link, it has two good options, to round it and cast it as string or round it using NSNumberFormatter.

Link: [Rounding a CGFLoat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427210/nsnumberformatter-for-rounding-up-float-values)

Hope this helps you!